# missing column header in R

Tags: r

So Ive been reading this site for a while, but its finally time to ask a question as i can't seem to find it elsewhere.
I have a file, saved in RDS format, when loaded looks like its missing first column header.

I am aware that the info is there, but I dont know how to obtain it. When I used dim, it indicated that there are only 2 columns, not 3. It seems like R isnt aware of the first column. 
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB8gZ.jpg)

If it was csv, I could avoid it by col.names and header=F, however I tried saving this RDS into csv, but then I lose the first column (obivously, was worth a shot).
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps they are rownames - try `row.names(df)`

Comment: Dear Andrew,

Yes, that was it. 
Thank you so much!